# Generalization of Griffith's calculation of the power radiated by a point charge when $\vec\beta(t_r)\neq 0$

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

In Griffiths's book, Introduction to Electrodynamics, Third Edition, Section 11.2, the author calculates the power radiated by a point charge $q$ in arbitrary motion. The calculation requires the expression for the acceleration field (or the radiation field) given by (in a notation slightly different from Griffiths) $${\vec E}_{\rm rad}=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0(1-\hat{n}\cdot{\vec\beta})^3}\frac{\hat{n}\times[(\hat{n}-\vec\beta)\times\dot{\vec\beta}]}{cR}$$ where $${\vec R}=\vec r-\vec r'=R\hat{n},$$ and $$\vec\beta=\vec v/c$$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the charge. Just before Eq. 11.68, the author assumes that the charge is instantaneously at rest at the retarded time $t_r$ so that $\vec\beta(t_r)=\vec0$. But for motion along an arbitrary curve, there is no reason why the charge should be at rest at any instant of time.

Griffiths's calculation is not completely general. [A footnote on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula#cite_note-2) says that the general case (i.e. $\vec\beta(t_r)\neq 0)$ is treated in Griffiths. I don't find it in my book. Does anyone know how to derive the formula for the radiated power without assuming that the charge was instantaneously at rest at the retarded time i.e. without assuming  $\vec\beta(t_r)= 0)$?

Comment: I don't think he is trying to assume V=0, he is just ignoring that contribution as this is not "radiated" energy, in the form of em waves. The radiated energy is energy that is caused by acceleration. Including the energy that is present due to the charges velocity, would not be considered radiated energy, this is just the power transfered due to the charge moving in a certain direction (as the field strength increases as it moves towards a point, similar to an electrostatic field moving). The definition of "Radiated energy" needs to be due to an EM wave propagating at C

Comment: If you would like to find the total energy flowing across some surface, calculate the poynting vector from the lienard wichert fields and integrate about a surface. Griffiths result is not a general result that applies to all distributions

Comment: @jensenpaull Please see the Wikipedia footnote I just added.

Comment: Radiated energy IMO is a definition game, I think the most suitable is to just use the acceleration field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Griffiths derives the power in an arbitrary frame by taking the Larmor formula (valid when $v = 0$) and boosting it to a frame where $v \neq 0$.  The result is Equation (11.72), which is valid even when $v \neq 0$.  In obtaining this, he has to introduce a geometric quantity into the formula to account for the differing rates of emission and absorption due to the motion of the source (p. 462 *et seq.* in the third edition.)